# FFMPEG: convert a mp4 to mp3 using ffmpeg-android ndk

Tags: android, video, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I want to convert a video file of `mp4` format to audio file of `mp3` format. It is simple through command line but i cannot find how can i convert it through `jni`. Not sure which library and which function to call. Any help regarding this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Well, this was not available in 2013, but today this can be easily achieved with the [mobile-ffmpeg](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg) library. The nice thing about it is that you call it through **jni** but at the same time you can use the familiar command-line syntax to perform your ffmpeg tasks.